# android toolbar for pre lollipop devices

Tags: android, toolbar

I encountered many issues when I changed from ActionBar to Toolbar. i have listed them here

**1** ) I have many fragments which are added/replaced using backstack. everything was working fine when i press back button but when I changed to Toolbar, application closes when i press back button.

**2** ) Background of popup menu is black.

```
<item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu</item>
<style name="PopupMenu" parent="@android:style/Widget.PopupMenu">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

even this didnt worked.

If I use AppCompat.Light theme, background color of popupmenu is white, but then NavigationIndicator icons and all that becomes black

**3** ) This is my menu style. Here item with id "add" is not shown instead i have used showAsAction as always. it is there in the menu (menu that inflates when i press that 3 vertical dots button), but the icon is not visible.

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context=".com.hirak.assistere_doit.do_it_main_screen">

<item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="Settings" />
<item android:id="@+id/add"
    android:icon="@drawable/add"
    android:showAsAction="always"/>

</menu>
```

Comment: i forgot to mention that my main aim to use toolbar is that new navigation drawer indicator. if i can get that indicar in action bar, i wont bother about using toolbar

Answer (score 6):

In order to style the popup menu, you need to apply a popup

`<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        app:theme="@style/ActionBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        app:popupTheme="@style/ToolbarPopup" />`

and then in your theme, override the values you want changed

```
<style name="ToolbarPopup" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Light.PopupMenu">
    <item name="android:background">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
</style>
```

to change the navigation indicators to white, add to your toolbar

```
<style name="ActionBar" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar">
    ...
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/white</item>
    <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

As for the back button issues, I would need more info - code etc.

Answer (score 0):

About back button issues.
 
I had the same problem when i changed to Toolbar.
 
Problem was in using **`FragmentManager instead of support.v4.app.FragmentManager`**. `Creating FragmentManager object by getSupportFragmentManager()` method and changing all fragments import to `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` -  solved this problem for me.